# Zipping files according to filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip, filenames

Daily we receive five files like this:

`vi_250000364846.dqa_report.xlsx`
`vi_250000364846.3553_report`
`vi_250000364846.MSR_report`
`vi_250000364857.3553_report`
`vi_250000364857.dqa_report.xlsx`

The numbers in the filename differ each day, but they will be the same for the three required files. I need to send those three files only to a compressed zip folder.

I've written the following code, but it's using the first file multiple times and displays the same value five times:

```
@echo on  
set LOGFILE=batch.log  
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%  
exit /B  

:LOG  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
set n=0  
set count=0  
set vector[%n%]=0  
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\Test"') do (  
set filename=%%i  
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ("%filename%") do (  
   set vector[!n!]=%%a  
  for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%v in ('set vector[%n%]')  do @echo %%v  
)  
 set /A n+=1  
)
```

I'm not sure why it's not taking the second file as a parameter. I'm trying to create an array of the numbers in all the five filenames and then compare those array values.

Please help me to find out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Neither from your code nor from the description it is clear **what** 3 files you want to zip. The first `for /f` seems unneccessary as you just use it to enumerate the files and the 3rd one is misplaced; it should be outside of the oter for /f.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple places where you used eager expansion (with `%` delimiters) where you should have used delayed expansion (with `!` delimiters). Fixing that seems to get the behavior you want:

```
@echo on  
set LOGFILE=batch.log  
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%  
exit /B  

:LOG  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
set n=0  
set count=0  
set vector[%n%]=0  
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\Test"') do (  
set filename=%%i  
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ("!filename!") do (  
   set vector[!n!]=%%a  
  for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%v in ('set vector[!n!]')  do @echo %%v  
)  
 set /A n+=1  
)
```

To be clear, the changes I made are to:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ("%filename%") do (
```

changed to:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ("!filename!") do (
```

and:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%v in ('set vector[%n%]')  do @echo %%v
```

changed to:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%v in ('set vector[!n!]')  do @echo %%v
```

Without those changes, `%filename%` is always expanding to the empty string, and `%n%` is always expanding to 0 (the value it was set to when the outer `for` began); in the latter case, this only screwed up your output (you correctly used `!n!` when assigning to `vector`, so it had the correct values, it's just that you only printed the first entry even when you had added entries in subsequent indices).